# (Solved) How do I import updated Wordpress product descriptions?

Tags: database, wordpress, product, updates

I have a CSV file with 500 rows and two columns: product id and description. How would I go about updating the descriptions in Wordpress with SQL? I am pretty decent with SQL but not sure what fields I am targeting.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Nobody (except you) knows how the current database looks like, so nobody can provide help

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to update description through sql , there is an easy walk around, use worpdress product listing page you can import products from there and you can match columns from there
, hope this helps

Comment: Okay I will have a look, thanks! And LOL worpdress.